# Mesh shrivels when simulating cloth

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to make a long mesh like this to be floppy, for an alien-looking plant project. It has this shape:
[image]

When I do the cloth simulation, though, this happens:
[image]

The nose of it shrivels and it gets wrinkly. How would I avoid that shriveling while still mantaining the floppiness? Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the *Soft Body* physics instead.

Or you could give the cloth simulation to a cage (a simplified version of your current object), and give your object a *Mesh Deform* modifier with this cage as *Object*:

[image]

Comment: That cage idea seems like a pretty good way to go about it. Since I'm fairly new to Blender, I had no idea that  was a thing. Thank you!